# Merging SVN Repositories: I loaded old repository onto an existing repository. How do I switch my working copy?

Tags: svn, switch-statement, dump

I'm trying to merge multiple Subversion repositories into a single repository without too much hassle on my users.

I did roughly the following:

```
> svnadmin dump old_repo > old_repo.dump
> svnadmin load combined_repo --parent-dir old_repo_path < old_repo.dir
> cd old_working_dir
> svn switch http://server/combined_repo_root/old_repo_path
svn: Repository UUID '47910ef9-e52f-470c-a5c0-0a25e3386063' doesn't match expected UUID '4b1b6bb6-f4d7-4649-9891-0302873c425d'
```

So switch doesn't work the way I expected, and obviously I can't make multiple old repos share the same repository id. What are my alternatives to perform the switch?

Comment: Also tried svn switch --relocate <OLD_URL> <COMBINED_URL> with similar results.

Answer (score 1):

Don't switch the repository in place, create a new working copy using `svn checkout` instead.

If you have any pending changes use

```
$ svn diff > changes.patch
```

to save the changes and restore in the new directory with

```
$ patch -p0 < changes.patch
```